# Do you know a good web CMS to manage a sports team?

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a web based CMS that enables me to manage a sport team, I need the following features:

- Calendar**
- Schedule events (sync with the calendar, RSS feed), it would be great if I could schedule a weekly event too, so that I don't have to schedule it by hand each week**
- Announcements (same RSS feed as events)**
- A place where I can put some documentation, rules**
- Keep track of the matches and scores
- Photo and video gallery

** means feature is required; otherwise optional

Any technology for the CMS is probably fine, though I would prefer an SQLite-based CMS.

Comment: I don't think this is a question for SO, but check [google apps for business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html), you can have all of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that would need little customisation I think your best bet would be something like Wordpress with the [Diarise Wootheme](http://www.woothemes.com/2010/04/diarise/) or possibly [Moodle](http://moodle.org/).